# similarity between two strings in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to calculate the similarity between two strings in a dataframe, so i've searched and found the `levehstein distance` which doesn't help me.

In my case the strings are separated by a comma `,` so i want to calculate the similarity between two columns, and here is an example:

[image]

like shown in this image i want to comapre the list of strings of col 1 with the list of strings in col2 and calculate the similarity between them like this : {number of paragraphes in col1 that matches with the ones in col2}/{number of paragraphes in col 2}
so please if you can help me , or is there a function to calculate similarity like this ,because i've searched and didn't find anything on this particular case

PS: Knowing that paragraphes are separated by a comma `,`

Comment: For such a specific calculation, no predefined functions exist. You can define your one function and iterate over the dataframe rows manually. For the comparison of the two strings the python function `.split(',')` can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spark **inbuilt** functions `array_intersect,size,split,concat_ws` funcitons.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+------------+------------+
#|        Col1|        Col2|
#+------------+------------+
#|    ABCD,MGF|ABCD,AADD,SC|
#|ABCD,AABD,CV|ABCD,CV,DDXF|
#+------------+------------+

df.withColumn("Similarity",concat_ws("/",size(array_intersect(split(col("col1"),","),split(col("col2"),","))),size(split(col("col2"),",")))).show()
#+------------+------------+----------+
#|        Col1|        Col2|Similarity|
#+------------+------------+----------+
#|    ABCD,MGF|ABCD,AADD,SC|       1/3|
#|ABCD,AABD,CV|ABCD,CV,DDXF|       2/3|
#+------------+------------+----------+
```